# Deleting the selected Row from DataGrid and Database C#

Tags: c#, sql

I know this topic is a frequently asked question,but i can't figure out the problem here.

The problem is my remove button is removing the row below the selected row.And as an extended problem there is an error while trying to delete the last row.

I think the issue is in `dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value`

This supposed to take the Id value from the grid and delete the according record but it's not working properly. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
private void removeButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=TEST;Initial Catalog=TEST;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=123;Password=123"))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            conn.Open();
            for (int i = dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
            {
                DataGridViewRow delrow = dataGridView2.Rows[i];
                if (delrow.Selected == true)
                {
                    dataGridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
                    try
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM dbo.deneme_log WHERE id=" + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value + "";
                        cmd.Connection = conn;
                        int count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: First, you delete row `i` from the grid and then you are trying to delete it from the database, but you access it by the same index `i` which points now to the next row. As an easy fix you need to use `delrow` variable for construction `cmd.CommandText` value.

Comment: @IliaMaskov Just put it as an answer to the question, I think.

Comment: @IliaMaskov dude you are a genious.I just swapped the row deletion line after the database deletion and it's fixed.Lol i was trying to figure this out for like 2 hours now.Thanks a lot

Comment: How did you fill the DGV?  Is the DataSource a DataTable?  If the source is a DataTable you need to delete row from DataTable and then do an Update which will automatically delete item from DataBase.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you delete row `i` from the grid and then you are trying to delete it from the database, but you access it by the same index `i` which points now to the next row. As an easy fix you need to use `delrow` variable for construction `cmd.CommandText` value. And also there is the `SelectedRows` property in the `GridView` so you don't need to walk throw all rows.